# Consume events in MFC's CStatic and pass them to the parent

Tags: events, mfc, event-bubbling

I am building MFC application where there is CDialog with child control derived from CStatic on it.

I want to receive mouse events for CStatic control so I set `"Notify"` for it to true. Now I am able to receive message events through message map directly in `MyStatic`:

```
class CMyStatic : public CStatic
{
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point); // Gets invoked
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
}
```

The problem is that from now the parent CDialog is not receiving mouse events when mouse is over `MyStatic` child. I can send them from `MyStatic` manually but is there any way to let them go through automatically? And still be able to receive them also on `MyStatic` using message maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're misunderstanding. SS_NOTIFY does not cause your CStatic to receive messages, it causes the CStatic to relay messages back to the parent. So "Now I am able to receive message events through message map directly in MyStatic" is based on a false premise.

This is an important point to make because a control can only receive messages for *itself*, not for its children, unless those children 'play along' by relaying messages or by doing other tricks (global hooking, ...) ; but those cases are the exception, the 'normal' way is that each window receives messages for itself.

So that answers your question: no, there is no way to let both a parent (your CDialog) and a child (your CStatic) receive mouse events without doing so 'manually' or getting involved in tedious message routing hacks. So in your case, what you need to do is GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, ...) etc, manually recreating the WPARAM and LPARAM values; or calling OnLButtonDown directly on the CDialog: GetParent()->OnLButtonDown(...). You'll have to think about what mouse coordinates you pass back to CDialog though, you may need to translate them to the CDialog's client coordinates.

Comment: Roel, thank you for explanation. However unless setting SS_NOTIFY I was not able to receive messages using message map. Maybe this is some weird MFC behavior?

Comment: Try catching WM_MOUSEMOVE in your CStatic and doing SetFocus() in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the base OnLButtonDown handler, the message should be sent to the parent.

```
CMyStatic::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CStatic::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);

    // custom handling
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I had to put `GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, GetDlgCtrlID() | WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16, (LONG) GetSafeHwnd());` in my CMyStatic::OnLButtonDown() method to make this work.  Similarly for WM_LBUTTONUP and CMyStatic::OnLButtonUp().  That technique was suggested by [this page](http://www.tenouk.com/visualcplusmfc/visualcplusmfc16b.html).