# MFC VC++ CStatic only receiving WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a small MFC Document View App in C++ and I am having some trouble receiving messages in a class that inherits from CStatic. I have managed to create the CStatic derivative and it is visible on my View however my message handlers are not being fired.

When using Spy++ it seems that window is only receiving `WM_NCHITTEST` and it is returning `HTTRANSPARENT`, which according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx) means:

"In a window currently covered by another window in the same thread (the message will be sent to underlying windows in the same thread until one of them returns a code that is not HTTRANSPARENT)."

Here is an exert from Spy++:

```
<000001> 001D1350 S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:128 yPos:167
<000002> 001D1350 R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTTRANSPARENT
<000003> 001D1350 S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:128 yPos:166
<000004> 001D1350 R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTTRANSPARENT
<000005> 001D1350 S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:128 yPos:165
<000006> 001D1350 R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTTRANSPARENT
<000007> 001D1350 S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:128 yPos:164
<000008> 001D1350 R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTTRANSPARENT
```

This seems strange because the CStatic derivative is the only child window of my view. I created it like this:

```
Create(pItem->Value->GetBuffer(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, Rect, Parent);
ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

where `Parent` is a pointer to the `CView`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo: public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Foo)
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    virtual void CreateCtrl(CWnd * Parent, POINT TopLeft, SIZE sz);

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
void Foo::CreateCtrl(CWnd * Parent, POINT TopLeft, SIZE sz)
{
    CRect Rect(TopLeft, sz);
    Create(pItem->Value->GetBuffer(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, Rect, Parent);
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Foo, CStatic)     
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void Foo::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{   
    AfxMessageBox("Hello World!");
    __super::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: What message handlers are not being fired? Have you searched SO with `CStatic`?

Comment: The main one is `OnLButtonUp`. I did have a look around SO and though some questions are similar I don't think they are the same as mine.

Comment: can you post some code of how you are declaring your CStatic derived class and your `OnLButtonUp` handler?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Microsoft's article ["About Static Controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760767.aspx#static_control_default_message_processing), and in particular this part:

> WM_NCHITTEST: Returns HTCLIENT if the control style is SS_NOTIFY; otherwise, returns HTTRANSPARENT.

Once the window returns `HTTRANSPARENT` from WM_NCHITTEST, all further mouse messages go to the window underneath it in Z-order; in your case, the parent view. The window is "transparent" as far as mouse handling is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of experimenting, it looks like setting and additional `SS_NOTIFY` style in `Foo::CreateCtrl()` gets MFC to call `Foo::OnLButtonUp()`.

I am a bit confused with this style setting, specially after reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086020/1850797); the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx) for `SS_NOTIFY` just says "Sends the parent window STN_CLICKED, STN_DBLCLK, STN_DISABLE, and STN_ENABLE notification codes when the user clicks or double-clicks the control."

Maybe without the `SS_NOTIFY` style, it doesn't have to receive messages because they are not relayed to the parent?

Anyway, adding the `SS_NOTIFY` style seems to make it work!